# prevent pandas from removing spaces in numbers in text columns

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to load CSV file into pandas dataframe. CSV is semicolon delimited. Values in text columns are in double quotation marks.

File in question: https://www.dropbox.com/s/1xv391gebjzmmco/file_01.csv?dl=0

In one of the text columns (*'TYTUL'*) i have following value:

> "00 307 1457 212"

I specify the column as ***str*** but when i print or export results to excel I get

> 003071457212

instead of

> 00 307 1457 212

How do I prevent pandas from removing spaces?

Here is my code:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv(r'file_01.csv'
                     ,sep = ';'
                     ,quotechar = '"'
                     ,names = ['DATA_OPERACJI'
                               ,'DATA_KSIEGOWANIA'
                               ,'OPIS_OPERACJI'
                               ,'TYTUL'
                               ,'NADAWCA_ODBIORCA'
                               ,'NUMER_KONTA'
                               ,'KWOTA'
                               ,'SALDO_PO_OPERACJI'
                               ,'KOLUMNA_9']
                     ,usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
                     ,skiprows = 38
                     ,skipfooter = 3
                     ,encoding = 'cp1250'
                     ,thousands = ' '
                     ,decimal = ','
                     ,parse_dates = [0,1]
                     ,converters = {'OPIS_OPERACJI': str
                                    ,'TYTUL': str
                                    ,'NADAWCA_ODBIORCA': str
                                    ,'NUMER_KONTA': str}
                     ,engine = 'python'
                     )

df.TYTUL.replace([' +', '^ +', ' +$'], [' ', '', ''],regex=True,inplace=True) #this only removes excessive spaces

print(df.TYTUL)
```

I also came up with a workaround (comment #workaround) but I would like to ask if there is a better way.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv(r'file_01.csv'
                     ,sep = ';'
                     ,quotechar = '?' #workaround
                     ,names = ['DATA_OPERACJI'
                               ,'DATA_KSIEGOWANIA'
                               ,'OPIS_OPERACJI'
                               ,'TYTUL'
                               ,'NADAWCA_ODBIORCA'
                               ,'NUMER_KONTA'
                               ,'KWOTA'
                               ,'SALDO_PO_OPERACJI'
                               ,'KOLUMNA_9']
                     ,usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
                     ,skiprows = 38
                     ,skipfooter = 3
                     ,encoding = 'cp1250'
                     ,thousands = ' '
                     ,decimal = ','
                     ,parse_dates = [0,1]
                     ,converters = {'OPIS_OPERACJI': str
                                    ,'TYTUL': str
                                    ,'NADAWCA_ODBIORCA': str
                                    ,'NUMER_KONTA': str}
                     ,engine = 'python'
                     )

df.TYTUL.replace([' +', '^ +', ' +$'], [' ', '', ''],regex=True,inplace=True) #this only removes excessive spaces

df.TYTUL.replace(['^"', '"$'], ['', ''],regex=True,inplace=True) #workaround

print(df.TYTUL)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove this line from your read_csv code

```
,thousands = ' '
```

I tested it, the output is correct without this option

```
'00 307 1457 212'
```

Comment: That solves the problem that I described but generates another.

Columns that was float64 before are now object.

when you run: df.dtypes

before:
KWOTA                       float64
SALDO_PO_OPERACJI           float64

after:
KWOTA                        object
SALDO_PO_OPERACJI            object

Comment: You can add these two columns in your converters option to make them float. OR change the data type by doing df.KWOTA.astype(float)